# LOCAL_CFLAGS := -fstack-protector-all not working android flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, security, android-ndk

I am building an app using `Flutter` and did a security scan using `MobSF`.
It is reporting following issue again and again for multiple `.so` files.

```
This shared object does not have a stack canary value added to the stack. Stack canaries are used to detect and prevent exploits from overwriting return address. Use the option -fstack-protector-all to enable stack canaries.
```

Issue points to setting `compiler flags` to `-fstack-protector-all` and following is what I did to achieve this.

1. Added `Android.mk` files with following content:

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
    
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_MODULE    := keys

    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := keys.c
    
    LOCAL_CFLAGS := -fstack-protector-all
    
    LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -fstack-protector-all

    LOCAL_CXXFLAGS := -fstack-protector-all

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

2. Connected `Android.mk` to android project using following code in `build.gradle` file.

```
 ndkVersion '21.3.6528147'
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }
```

**Outcome of this integration**:-
App compiles successfully but when scanned with `MobSF` again, it still reports the same error as mentioned above. As I mentioned `flags` in `Android.mk` file that means it is global for all libraries but still same outcome.

Looking forward for solutions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Antonycx I sent an email to flutter security team and they said they are using some other technology better than this which is more efficient and secure